# How to get bash to reevaluate $(date) when part of a background job - if possible

Tags: freebsd, socat

OS FreeBSD-12.2

I have a virtual printer setup using `socat`.  The `socat` command runs in the background.  It spawns a system shell that processes the input stream and sends it to `gpcl6` to create pdf documents.  The output goes to a file in a specific directory.  The file name is meant to contain a timestamp `$(date -Iseconds)`.  The problem is that this timestamp is only evaluated when the `socat` command is started and not thereafter.  My question is: Is there a way to make this re-evaluation happen each time a data stream arrives?

The full command is:

*HPNP=4178 socat TCP4-LISTEN:4178,bind=192.168.216.179,fork,reuseaddr,su=hp3000 SYSTEM:"sed -r '1s/^.{42}//' | cat /var/spool/hp3000/forms/hll_inv_ljiii_85.ovl - | gpcl6 -dNOSAFE -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/var/spool/hp3000/np4178/HP3000-INV-"$(date -Iseconds)"-%03u.pdf -" &*

I have experimented with single, double, and no quotes.  The command launches with all three options.  However, single and double quote produce the same results, the timestamp is fixed to the time the command was started.  Without quotes the command launches but anything sent to it results in a constant stream of broken pipe errors:

```
2021/05/17 15:56:55 socat[17557] E write(5, 0x800b09000, 1460): Broken pipe
cat: stdout: Broken pipe
sed: stdout: Broken pipe
```

The socat man page has this to say:

```
   SYSTEM:<shell-command>
          Forks a sub process that establishes communication with its
          parent process and invokes the specified program with system() .
          Please note that <shell-command> [string] must not contain ','
          or "!!", and that shell meta characters may have to be
          protected.  After successful program start, socat writes data to
          stdin of the process and reads from its stdout.
          Option groups: FD,SOCKET,EXEC,FORK,TERMIOS
          Useful options: path, fdin, fdout, chroot, su, su-d, nofork,
          pty, stderr, ctty, setsid, pipes, sigint, sigquit
          See also: EXEC
```

I gather from this that a shell is forked but once on startup.  Is that the reason the $() construct is not being evaluated each time a data stream arrives? Is there anyway around this limitation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quotes are not affecting the `$(date)` command, so it's always evaluated exactly once immediately before the `socat` command is executed.

Simplifying your command for illustrative purposes here's what I hope is a slightly easier view that shows how `$(date)` isn't inside quotes

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:flags SYSTEM:"sed | gpcl6 file-"$(date)"-suffix"
#                              ^in quotes        ^out    ^in     ^out
```

If you put it inside double-quotes it will be evaluated just like now (except that any spaces in the resulting output will remain as spaces rather than word split points). If you put it inside single-quotes, the shell that `socat` calls to evaluate the `SYSTEM` option will evaluate it each time it's called:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:flags SYSTEM:'sed | gpcl6 file-$(date)-suffix'
```

You can see this in action with this pair of commands, run on two different systems:

```
# Server
socat TCP4-LISTEN:4178,fork,reuseaddr SYSTEM:'cat >socat.$(date +%H%M%S).txt'

# Client
echo boo | nc remoteServer 4178

# Sever
ls șocat.*.txt
```

Putting this change back into your original code you should get this (notice that for convenience I also swapped the type of quotes used by the `sed` command):

```
HPNP=4178 socat TCP4-LISTEN:4178,bind=192.168.216.179,fork,reuseaddr,su=hp3000 SYSTEM:'sed -r "1s/^.{42}//" | cat /var/spool/hp3000/forms/hll_inv_ljiii_85.ovl - | gpcl6 -dNOSAFE -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/var/spool/hp3000/np4178/HP3000-INV-$(date -Iseconds)-%03u.pdf -' &
```

Comment: I will try that.  I never considered the double quotes surrounding the SYSTEM option command string.

Comment: It works.  Thank you very much.